# Traversing Two Json Arrays with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a page that ng-repeats a ng-template for every element in a json array.  The Json array also has sub arrays.  There is a ng-repeat at the end of the template that takes care of the sub arrays.  They display nested within spans.

So basically, the code shows a visual representation of the json hierarchy.

Now onto the problem.  There is a second json that has the same hierarchy.  You can think of it as a way of comparing the two jsons with the same structure.  If I was able to traverse this at the same time, I'd be in shape.  Problem is, I don't think there is a way for angular's ng-repeat to do that.

So my solution so far is to have a recursive javascript function.  Base case is if it is top level.  if it isn't top level, it calls itself but this time with the $parent and and the $index of the $parent.  So this works how it sounds, it gets the top level index of the array in every sub group.  Problem is, I need a way to save the index's as I traverse back down the parallel json array. I can't return an array of index's because that would break the recursive function. But if I could somehow do that, I could traverse back down through the parallel array and then return the group to compare.

Is there a way to do this?  And/or is there a better way of doing this.  Note I CANNOT combine the two json objects as they are needed elsewhere.

Comment: sounds like trying to do too much with ng-repeat. How about doing the processing in code, constructing a new object with your results? Then ng-repeat over the results object, not the source objects.

Comment: So, combining the two objects into one object?  The problem with that is one of the json objects is going to get parsed on another page into a single string.  If I combined them, I would basically have duplicate data.  But I will look into it and see if there is a way to do it like that without the final string having duplicates.